# Excel wont combine columns into a single list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to combine multiple Excel columns into a single column.
Grabbing B2:E345, it worked for some of them, but the others came back with a #spill error or 0.
Some of these rows within these columns are blank. I pasted the below formula in Col F2.

How do I modify the below code to make it run without errors:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$345,+INT((ROW(A2)-1)/COLUMNS($B$2:$E$345)),MOD(ROW(A2)-1+COLUMNS($B$2:$E$345), COLUMNS($B$2:$E$345))+1)
```

Attached image, the expected result is that from col B to E we will have an ordered list in column F.
So for instance outputs should look like this:

```
B2
C2
D2
E2
```

[image]

Comment: Please include sample data and expected results. See [ask] a question with an [mcve].

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: it's 2008 it's for work :S

Comment: Later versions of Excel make this easier (which may not be much consolation to you right now). If you have access to these functions: SEQUENCE, LET, FILTER & SORT then there are multiple solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am going to ask my work to upgrade me.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Excel Office 365.

`=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,TRANSPOSE(B2:E345))&"</s></t>","//s")`.

Alternatively you can try this.

```
=LET(data,B2:E345,
     r,ROWS(data),
     c,COLUMNS(data),
     j,SEQUENCE(r*c),
     unfiltered, INDEX(data, MOD(j-1,r)+1, INT((j-1)/r)+1),
     FILTER(unfiltered, unfiltered<>0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only grabs the values from A1, it isn't copying the values from my other rows. :( same output as the code I have above.

Comment: Odd.  It works for two different machines with Office 365.  I tested a third with an older version.  It worked with the old array formulas as long as enough cells were selected and I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbb>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: The formula should work. However if your excel version is not O365 then you need to use `Index()` function.

Comment: The code works if the columns have one value then it understands what I am trying to do, it doesn't work where there are multiple values across my columns, I am getting a #spill error. It is O365 I am using.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a #SPILL unless there is something in the way or the formula is entered multiple times.  Both solutions should be entered in just one cell.

Comment: Hmm, I have 4 columns some of them have null values some of them might have one value and others multiple values in the same row. I entered the formula and dragged it down, but it is just not copying my multi valued column data. Do I need to have an if clause in there to make it copy the multi valued cells? I have no idea how to write formulas this complex, just tried to follow a YouTube tutorial. 

Comment: In Excel O365.  you should be able to enter the formula in one cell.  The results should spill into the other cells.  Copying the formula to more cells will cause a #SPILL error.